# Controlling the ref type in a Vapi file

Tags: vala, vapi

I'm trying to write a [Vapi file for MessagePack](https://github.com/geoffjay/msgpack-vala) and am having a couple of issues, the first being that the resulting `msgpack_object_print` is incorrect because of the reference type of one of the parameters. The header file expects

```
void msgpack_object_print(FILE* out, msgpack_object o);
```

and my Vapi file contains

```
[CCode (instance_pos = 1.1)]
public void print (Posix.FILE out);
```

which generates the C output

```
msgpack_object_print (_tmp13_, &obj);
```

where `obj` is type `msgpack_object *`. This creates the error

```
examples/simple.c:173:34: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘msgpack_object_print’
```

and it disappears if I remove the `&` from the generated C. So I'm wondering what my Vapi should contain to result in the correct output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can designated your `msgpack_object` class as `[SimpleType]` and it will be copied by value rather than by reference.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a partial VAPI for MessagePack if you want to contribute back by using and testing it.

https://github.com/valum-framework/vala-extra-vapis/blob/msgpack/msgpack.vapi

Like already said, you need to use the `[SimpleType]` annotation on the class to have your type passed by value.

EDIT: Just adding that for bindings, it's a good thing to keep them in [nemequ/vala-extra-vapis](https://github.com/nemequ/vala-extra-vapis) repository.

Comment: Hmm, I search github for that before starting and came up empty. I definitely wouldn't have started one had I seen it. Thanks.